# Application port number changed

Tags: windows-services, ip-address, telnet, port-number

I face a problem where the port number of the application (MetaProducts Offline Explorer) has been changed(800 to 7000) and dont know how can it automatically changed.

I trying to run telnet command in the server itself, e.g: `telnet <ip address> <port number>`
the result was a blank command screen. what does this mean? and what is the expected result if the port number is not using by an application?

what are the thing I can check for why the port number is changed?

thank you in advanced.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question. What makes you think the port number changed? It just sounds like the application isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

[Netstat.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true) is part of OS. To list all open ports and processes that are listening or sending on these ports, type this command in cmd window:

```
netstat -noa
```

Comment: how can I map the PID? I view in task manager, but some of the PID appear in netstat but not in Task Manager, so I not able to locate the PID

Comment: Tasklist.exe is part of OS. This will print out all processes. You can also use Task Manager -- but then you will have to click "Show processes for all users".

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for a port to just change. The application has to intentionally close the socket that is using the old port and then open a socket on a new port.

Comment: regardless whether it is intentionally change or not, how can I investigate the port number is below to a certain application?

Comment: Go to http://www.sysinternals.com and download the TCPView utility. It can show you which running processes are using which ports.